# Is line-height variable between browsers

Tags: html, css

So I've done a bit of googling around and can't seem to find a clear answer.

Does the line-height property vary between browsers at all or is it just standard and font-size is all that we need to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, line-height is not set by the browser at all.

Comment: heh, forgot that this was still open. I don't remember what the issue was exactly, but it looks like if lineHeight at all matters, you've gotta set it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It's a standard across all browsers based on the font-size. http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp/

Comment: There is no standard for the value for this.

Answer (score -2):

To be safe you can use a css reset file ( http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ) at the start of all your pages. This resets a lot of the browser inconsistencies.